# WSS4J : WSSecurityEngine : processSecurityHeader()

Tags: web-services, ws-security, wss4j

Is it wrong to call WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader in more than one layers while processing an inbound request?

For eg: 1st layer intercepts and calls processSecurityHeader to validate the UserName/SAML tokens while the down stream layer calls processSecurityHeader to decrypt and verify the signature.